# Local database support Vender

Tags: apache-flex, air, local-database

I am just new in Flex/ARI development.

I Want to used local machine  database in my one ARI (Desktop) Application,

So which database vender are available for local database support Windows OS, like SQlite....etc . Which one is best and faster for big databases.

Also its very good if their is no any driver, software do not need to install on client machine for database.

Answer (score 0):

The only DB which AIR supports natively is SQLLite. It means AIR runtime has built in SQLLite instance.

Comment: As for me personally I have no any experience with large data sets. But you can find corresponding discussions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1033309/680503) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4746576/680503). I suppose as far as you haven't any convenient alternatives using Adobe AIR you should optimize your solution (database scheme, queries) but not trying to choose some third party solution with potential problems (cross-platform issues, reliable communication and maintenance).

Comment: Large data sets are relative.  Frankly, all DBs can be optimized for it, but if you're really doing intense calculations on your data, I'm not sure why you're holding the data on the front end to start with.